# Can You Cash A Bank Guarantee?

Tags: banking, co-sign

Can you cash a bank guarantee and if so where?

Answer (score 2):

A bank guarantee can be cashed at the bank that issued it, so long as you are the debtor involved in the defaulted debt, and the debt in question is, indeed, defaulted.

A Bank Guarantee is simply a financial tool that allows a bank to "cosign" for an individual, and carries much the same result on default as an individual cosigner would.

Comment: Thanks! Also, I found out that note buyers can buy Bank Guarantees since they're a type of promissory note after all.